# makefile not cleaning up everything

Tags: makefile

I am trying to figure out why my makefile is leaving behind all the *.o files. The `clean:` section clearly has:

`rm *.o *.s *.bc fib fact1 fact2 *~`

I've tried adding -f and several other parameters to rm without any luck. What would be causing these to not be removed? Here is the full makefile. I call it with

```
make -f Makefile
```

---

```
OFILES= fib.o
OFILES1= fact1.o
OFILES2= fact2.o
CPATH=~/cse/llvm/bin/
LLVMASY=$(CPATH)llvm-as
LLVMOPT=$(CPATH)opt
LLVMLC=$(CPATH)llc
AS=clang -c
LD=clang

all: fib fact1 fact2

fib: $(OFILES)
        $(LD) $(OFILES) $(LIBS) -o $@

fact1: $(OFILES1)
        $(LD) $(OFILES1) $(LIBS) -o $@

fact2: $(OFILES2)
        $(LD) $(OFILES2) $(LIBS) -o $@

%.o : %.s
        $(AS) $< -o $@

%.s : %.bc
        $(LLVMLC) $< -O=3 -tailcallopt -o $@

%.bc : %.llvm
        $(LLVMASY) $< -o $@

clean:
        rm *.o *.s *.bc fib fact1 fact2 *~
```

---

**EDIT:** I should have added that all of the *.s and *.bc files remove successfully. It's only the *.o files that stay.

---

***Disclaimer:*** *This is homework but this is not the part I'm being evaluated on. My question is out of pure curiosity.*

Comment: What does `ls -ls *.o` gives?

Comment: fact1.o
fact2.o
fib.o

Comment: This is not the output of `ls -ls *.o`; you should have one line per each file with the owner, the permissions, the mtime. The `-ls` options to `ls` is important. Or try `/bin/ls -l -s *.o` and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: What does `rm *.o` from the command line do?

Comment: rm *.o removes all the *.o files. It's just not working from the Makefile. It's the weirdest thing.

Comment: No, that's `ls *.o`, not `rm *.o`.  I assume you are really using `make clean` (see my answer)?

Comment: trojanfoe: I answered you too. rm *.o removes all the *.o files from the directory as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are invoking `make` using `make -f Makefile` then you are not invoking the `clean` target, you will invoke the first (`all`) target.

Try:

```
$ make clean
```

Comment: "make clean" successfully removed the rest of the files. I'm curious now how I'm supposed to properly call the Makefile since "make -f Makefile" doesn't perform the entire rm function. I was told the professor wanted it in our .zip so that he could grade them all with a script.

Comment: @fix Forget the `-f Makefile` part, as that is the default, you need to use two targets `all` to build and `clean` to clean.  Just `make` on its own will also invoke `all`.  Your question now makes no sense; you say that you can remove the files interactively (no permission problem), however `make clean` doesn't remove the `.o` files.  There is something missing and I cannot see what it is.

Comment: @fix When?  I don't remember seeing that.  So if `make clean` works, then isn't that problem solved?

Comment: Yes it is solved. Thank you. 4 lines up I said "make clean" successfully removed the rest of the files. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @fix Oh, when you said "the rest of the file" I thought you meant all but the `.o` files.  Your problem is solved (i.e. there was no problem).  The normal workflow is `make clean`, `make all` (use/copy files somewhere) then `make clean`.

Comment: So the purpose of this is so that the professor can clean out the directory before running his tests? So he will first use "make clean", then "make all", then test the outputs of my programs? It makes much more sense now. Thank you

I just realized. He probably gave us this Makefile so that he can make sure our llvm actually compiles and assembles, and that we haven't hard coded the solutions. I'm glad I asked this now.

Comment: @fix Yes, exactly.  There might be more targets like `test` or `install` which are dependant on the `all` target.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a `clean` file already exists. Check with `ls -l clean` then perhaps do `rm -v clean` in your terminal.

Also, check with `/bin/ls -l -s *.o` the ownership of such files. If at some point you did a `sudo make` they may be root owned so could not be `rm` by your ordinary user.

BTW, `make` will use a `Makefile` [if it has one](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Makefile-Names)  (it tries `GNUmakefile`, `makefile` and `Makefile` in that order)., so the `-f Makefile` is often not necessary.

Read the [documentation of GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html).

You should have `clean` a [`.PHONY` target](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets), e.g. add before your `clean:` rule

```
 .PHONY: clean
```

Use also [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/), perhaps as `remake -x` (or `remake -x clean` in your case) to debug your `Makefile`

The default target in `Makefile`-s is the first one, so is `all` (which should also be marked `.PHONY` BTW) in your case. To clean, run `make clean`.

Comment: I appended an edit to my question. I forgot to say that the clean works on all the other file extensions in the command. It's only the .o that do not delete. I believe this Makefile is necessary for the professor to auto-grade these from multiple students.

Comment: The `Makefile` is useful to build software. And you should take time to learn more about it (because using `make` -or some other builder- is nearly mandatory for real programming projects in C or C++). The GNU make documentation has a nice tutorial part.